# When using DES, how large would the key space be if we only use letters as characters?

Tags: des

Would it be safe? Or is it susceptible to brute force attacks or something else?

Answer (score 4):

A DES key is 56 bits. If we assume letters are ASCII encoded and take 8 bits each this means a DES key of only letters would be 7 letters long. Given that there are 26 letters in the roman alphabet we would have $26^7 \approx 2^{33}$ possible keys, or if we allow uppercase and lowercase, $52^7 \approx 2^{40}$ possible keys. Both keyspaces can quickly be enumerated with modern hardware and can easily be brute forced.

Comment: By another reading of the question, we use 8 ASCII characters A-Z as key, the low-order bit of each is ignored so we end up with 14 possible values, the keyspace is $14^8\lessapprox2^{30.5}$; or $28^8\lessapprox2^{38.5}$ with lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

If the intention is to stuff as many letters into a 56 bit DES key as possible, then you can get 11 (and a bit) in if you ignore case. You can decode the ASCII values to reduce the bits necessary to represent the characters.  Then 56/log(2;26) = 11.9.

So your key space would be 26^11 or 51.7 bits. That's almost full strength DES, but still  low for today's attack hardware. And of course DES is deprecated.